# How to migrate WIT from one collection to another?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a TFS2018 on-premise and Azure DevOps Server on-premise with many collections, and my goal is to migrate workitem from one collection to another within each server. 
" You can only move work items from one project to another project **within the organization or collection** . " - said https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#move-a-work-item-to-another-project .
What does it mean *within the organization* ? From one collection to another? :)
So is it really possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`within the organization or collection` - its just within Azure DevOps Organization (old VSTS) and Azure DevOps Server (or TFS) Collection. `Organization` = `Collection`. We can not move a work item into another collection or organization.

Answer (score 0):

TFS/Azure DevOps Server include three level, sever level--collection level--team project level

Azure DevOps Service include two level  organization(equal to default collection)level--team project level

**It's not able to migrate WIT from one collection to another in TFS server.**

Another evidence to prove is work item ID, it's unique in a single team project collection.

> **Work Item ID**
>
> The unique identifier that is assigned to a work item. **Work item IDs
>   are unique across all team projects and within a team project
>   collection.** Reference name=System.Id, Data type=Integer

If you are able to migrate across team project collection, how would you handle a work item with same ID in different collection.

Actually this ID is stored in TFS database and have various purposes such as work item query, TFS API and so on. Each collection has it own's database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move items from collection to collection, you'll need to export them to excel and then remap to the new collection/Azure DevOps Account and publish them, like Patrick mentioned those items will not have the same number they will be created with a new number.  There are others ways to do this, you can use the REST api and write some .NET or PowerShell code, or you can try and use Martin's migration tool (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration).